# Set default values in a JavaScript hash using values from an Array as keys

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a hash `h` and an array `a` like this:

```
h = {'data': {}};
arr = ['2017-01-01', '2017-02-01','2017-03-01', '2017-04-01', ....];
```

What is the most concise and efficient way to construct a default hash table as below in JavaScript:

```
// desired outcome for 'h'
h = {
 'data': {
    '2017-01-01': 0,
    '2017-02-01': 0,
    '2017-03-01': 0,
    '2017-04-01': 0,
    //...there can be more date values here
  }
}
```

I have implemented the solution below, but would like to know if there is more JavaScript-y (and hopefully more efficient) way to accomplish below:

```
arr.forEach(function(a) {
  h['data'][a] = 0;
});
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestion/answers!

Comment: `arr.forEach(e => h.data[e] = 0 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert your array into object with [**`.reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)  like

```
arr.reduce((o, key) => ({ ...o, [key]: 0}), {})
```

this will return you an object of form

```
 {
    '2017-01-01': 0,
    '2017-02-01': 0,
    '2017-03-01': 0,
    '2017-04-01': 0,
    //...there can be more date values here
  }
```

Now, you can simply assign this object to your `h.data` with `Object.assign` like

```js
var h = {'data': {}};
var arr = ['2017-01-01', '2017-02-01','2017-03-01', '2017-04-01'];

h.data = Object.assign(arr.reduce((o, key) => ({ ...o, [key]: 0}), {}));

console.log(h)
```

ps: in case you don't know `...` is called [**`spread operator`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Thank you for explaining step by step! In case you know, what would be more computationally efficient: my naive approach or your advanced one (assuming a size-able default array to set)? Or they are almost equal? I will wait for a few more hours to see who comments with more suggestion and then accept one of the answers. Hope you understand. :)

Comment: _what would be more computationally efficient_ ,  the one you're using should be more efficient. I just added another way to do it. :)

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up response. :) I'm glad that I learned a more advanced way to do it.